# Sequelize query for the following SQL:

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a SQL query that I want to write as a Sequelize query.

```
SELECT users.username, players.points, tournaments.date
FROM USERS
JOIN players ON users.id = players.UserId
JOIN Tournaments ON tournaments.id = players.TournamentId
WHERE players.player_checkedin_flag = 1 AND users.role = "user";
```

I have the following association in Players table:

```
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      // Foreign key to user_id
      Player.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false
        }
      });
      // Foreign key to tournament_id
      Player.belongsTo(models.Tournament, {
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false
        }
      });
```

In Users table,

```
{
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      // User has many Player data
      User.hasMany(models.Player);
    }
  }
}
```

And in Tournaments table:

```
{
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      // Tournament is connected to many player rows
      Tournament.hasMany(models.Player);
    }
  }
}
```

What is the corresponding sequelize query for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to perform [eager loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#nested-eager-loading) on those three models

```js
User.all({
    attributes: ['username'], // return only 'username' column from 'users' table
    include: [
        {
            model: Player, // eager load players on players.userId = users.id
            attributes: ['points'], // return only 'points' column from 'players' table
            include: [{ model: Tournament, attributes: ['date'] }] // nested eager load of 'tournaments' table on tournaments.playerId = players.id
        }
    ],
    where: {
        playerCheckedinFlag: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('Player.player_checkedin_flag', '=', 1),
        role: 'user'
    },
    raw: true // used the raw attribute to prevent creating User instances from the query result due to the fact that we return 3 fields from 3 different tables
}).(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

`sequelize` in the code above is the instance of Sequelize in which the models were defined. You can also check the documentation of [`sequelize.where()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere) method.

Comment: Thanks @piotrbienias, that's just what I was looking for. I will definitely read up on the documentation of sequelize.where().